# DataTable Fixed Column with Bootstrap's dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) with [Fixed Columns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/) extension and styling with Bootstrap. The columns I set up as fixed contain [Bootstrap's dropdown](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp) elements.
The problem is when I click on the dropdown element, my fixed column show the scroll bars or sometimes `overflow` were hidden as

[image]

Below is the code for initialization of my dataTable

```
var oTable = $('table').dataTable( {
bFilter : false,
ordering: false,
    sScrollX: "100%",
fixedColumns : {
    leftColumns : 0,
    rightColumns : 1
},
pagingType : "full_numbers",
"sDom" : '<"top">rt<"bottom"ifp><"clear">',
} );
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jwyeuh8m/14/). Has someone experience with this or how can I fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the dropmenu to body and some css to hide the fixed column overflow.

You can tweak the code as per your need.

Check Working Demo [**HERE**](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/pNWpjE?editors=1010)

CSS:

```
.DTFC_RightBodyLiner {
  overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('table').dataTable({
    bFilter: false,
    ordering: false,
    sScrollX: "100%",
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 0,
      rightColumns: 1
    },
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"ifp><"clear">',
  });

  $('.btn').click(function() {
    dropmenuPostion();
  })

  function dropmenuPostion() {
    // hold onto the drop down menu                                             
    var dropdownMenu;

    // and when you show it, move it to the body                                     
    $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {

      // grab the menu        
      dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');

      // detach it and append it to the body
      $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());

      // grab the new offset position
      var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();

      // make sure to place it where it would normally go (this could be improved)
      dropdownMenu.css({
        'display': 'block',
        'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
        'left': eOffset.left - 50
      });
    });

    // and when you hide it, reattach the drop down, and hide it normally                                                   
    $(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
      $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());
      dropdownMenu.hide();
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you sir ! ... It seems to fix problem. A small bug *can't click another while one dropdown menu was still open*.

Comment: Yay.... ! Thank you sir . I got it. As your codes , events will be nested again and again. Now I added the event handlings for `$(window).on('show.bs.dropdown'` and `$(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown'` after document has ready. It works fine everythings. Thanks a lot sir. Here is the last updated codes in JS Fiddle as you command https://jsfiddle.net/jwyeuh8m/22/. Have a nice day sir.

Comment: One problem ! This make mis-allign with [Bootstrap Select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select)

Comment: @Cataclysm you can modify the above code and target the dropemenu only for table. eg: `dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.table .dropdown-menu');`

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's no way to expand a width of column according to dropdown width using pure CSS or bootstrap. I think you can make it wider just setting a column fixed width like this:

```
      "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "160px", "targets": 6 }
  ],
```

Also you can make button as wide as column is by adding  class `btn-block` :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-block"...
```

Comment: I think it is not enough only expand the width of the column.It can't solve this issue because the last row still hidden the `overflow`. You can see the updated JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jwyeuh8m/18/

Answer (score 0):

You need to added `z-index` and remove `z-index` css to fixed column with bootstrap dropdown button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#examples-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    scrollX: true,
    fixedColumns: {
      left: 1,
      right: 1,
    },
    ajax: {
      // code ..
    },
    columns: [
      // code ...
    ],
  });
   
  $(document).on('click', '.link-focus', function(e) {
    $('.z-index-3').removeClass("z-index-3");
    $(this).closest("td").addClass("z-index-3");
  });
});
```

To see this tutorial [DataTable Fixed Column with Bootstrap's dropdown](https://laravelstaff.com/blogs/detail/datatable-fixed-column-with-bootstraps-dropdown)