# Materialise datatable overlap issue on fixed column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

I have following table

```
<table  class="table display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%" id="pageRoleTable">
                            <thead class="text-primary">
                            <th>Name</th>
                            @foreach($role as $key=>$value)
                            <th>{{$value->role_name}}</th>
                          @endforeach
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($page as $key=>$value)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$value->page_name}}</td>
                                @for($i=0;$i<count($role);$i++)
                                <td><div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" data-pageId="{{$value->id}}"  data-role="{{$role[$i]['id']}}" name="role_access" value="edit">

                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                    @endfor

                            </tr>

                                @endforeach


                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                @foreach($role as $key=>$value)
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-info"  data-role="{{$value->id}}">
                                        <span class="btn-label">
                                            <i class="material-icons">priority_high</i>
                                        </span>
                                            Info
                                            <div class="ripple-container"></div></button></td>
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

javascript

```
 $('#pageRoleTable').DataTable({


                    scrollY:        "300px",
                    scrollX:        true,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    paging:         false,
                    fixedColumns:   {
                        leftColumns: 4

                    }
                });
```

but after giving fixed column text content overlapping

[image]
Followed many answers but not helped me
[Datatable Fixed Column (Right Only) Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629614/datatable-fixed-column-right-only-issue)
[DataTable Fixed Column with Bootstrap's dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882626/datatable-fixed-column-with-bootstraps-dropdown)

can any one help me how  i can fix this

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed above issue by set the background color of `td and th`

```
.table tbody tr td{background:#fff /*set your own color*/} 
.table thead tr th{background:#fff /*set your own color*/}
```